# Change serialization deepness

Tags: json, spring, rest, spring-boot, serialization

I'm building a Restful API using Spring Boot and I'm running into a problem.
I have an entity called Event, it has the following attributes:
Long id, String title, Calendar date, List< User > owners (OneToMany), Double price.
The Entity, in turn, has the these attributes: Long id, String name, Calendar birthDate, List< Car > cars.
Entity Car, in turn, has Long id and String model as attributes.

The problem is, when I access the HTTP Method GET in my Event Controller, I get this JSON:

```
{  
    "id":1,
    "title":"Example event",
    "date":"2017-01-01",
    "owners":[  
        {  
            "id":1,
            "name":"Chuck Norris",
            "birthDate":"1000-05-12",
            "cars":[  
                {  
                    "id":1,
                    "model":"Shelby GT"
                }
            ]
        },
        {  
            "id":2,
            "name":"Bruce Lee",
            "birthDate":"1980-05-12",
            "cars":[  
                {  
                    "id":2,
                    "model":"Ford Maverick"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "price":5
}
```

Instead of serializing whole owners objects, I want just their ID, like this:

```
{  
    "id":1,
    "title":"Example event",
    "date":"2017-01-01",
    "owners":[  
        {  
            "id":1
        },
        {  
            "id":2
        }
    ],
    "price":5
}
```

How can I achieve this? And, is this correct to use? I think that serializing whole inner objects is a waste of resource because I don't need all their attributes at the moment, and it also causes loop with bi-directional relationships

Comment: What bi-directional relationships do you have?

Answer (score 1):

For this use-case I developed a small jackson module for dynamic filtering:

https://github.com/Antibrumm/jackson-antpathfilter

The second possibility would be to build DTOs for your endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Add `@JsonIgnore` Annotation to fields that you don't want to be serialized

Comment: But by doing so, I also won't be able to get those fields through User Controller, correct?

I need to get those fields there

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to return a custom view of the Event, but you may actually be better off with the full object, depending on what the user of your API needs to do with the Event. One option, especially since you commented that other calls need the full User object to be serialized, is to configure the ObjectMapper used in this method with a custom serializer for User.

Comment: Any tip of how I can do this?